# Seeking Ramchal's Hoker u'MeKubal in English

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, english, ramchal

Is the Ramchal's Hoker u'MeKubal available in English? I have already read Derech HaShem, Daas Tevunos, Mesillas Yesharim, and Ma'amar HaGeulas, so I would be interested  in other of his works in English as well.

Comment: Steven Finer, welcome to Judaism.SE and thank you for bringing your question here. You should consider registering your account to gain full access to the site's capabilities. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Welcome, Steveen Finer.  In addition to your search to broaden your knowledge of the Ramchal's teachings, the Ramchal himself may have said to keep reading Mesillas Yesharim, as much of what he writes are ideas which most people know, but forget in he day-to-day and must be reminded.

Comment: Can women learn Mesilas Yesharim? I am 27 years of age and have started Derech Hashem yet I am looking to learn more more more. - Do you know of other good sforim in Hebrew with English translation?

Comment: Hello @Dassi, and welcome to J.SE! This would be best expressed as a comment or as a separate question. Hope to see you around.

Comment: @HachamGabriel First time using this site I need direction please.

Comment: @Dassi Ask [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Women may and should learn Mesilat Yesharim and Derech Hashem in that order (HaRav Mansour Shalit"a).

Comment: klach pischei chochma is available in english

Comment: 3 more books available in one volume http://www.feldheim.com/way-of-torah.html